# Selection without duplicates. The same data, but different order

Tags: sql

I have some query that returns this:

```
model   model   speed   ram
1121    1233    750 128
1232    1233    500 64
1232    1260    500 32
1233    1121    750 128
1233    1232    500 64
1260    1232    500 32
```

I don't need repeating data as:

```
1121    1233    750 128
1233    1121    750 128
```

It's the same, but with different order of models.

All data stores in one table. There are a lot of PC's which have various models. I need PC's which have the same speed and ram, but I have some problem (described above).
Here's my query:

```
SELECT a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram
FROM PC AS a, PC AS b
WHERE a.speed = b.speed AND a.ram = b.ram AND a.model != b.model
ORDER BY a.model DESC, b.model ASC
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question but please use explicit joins. It makes the query way more readable.

Comment: Just an idea: If you want to see models with the same speed and ram, why show pairs of two? You may consider aggregating your rows per speed and ram and displaying a string listing all models, no matter if that's two, three or more.

Comment: What to do in case there's only one PC with a specific speed/ram or in case there are more than 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your existing query by changing `a.model != b.model` to `a.model > b.model` will give you the desired output.

```
SELECT a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram FROM PC AS a, PC AS b
WHERE a.speed = b.speed AND a.ram = b.ram 
and a.model > b.model
ORDER BY a.model DESC, b.model ASC
```

It is recommended to use explicit `JOIN` for your queries.

You can change your query like following.

```
SELECT a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram 
FROM PC AS a
inner join  PC AS b on a.speed = b.speed and a.ram = b.ram and  a.model > b.model      
ORDER BY a.model DESC, b.model ASC
```

Comment: Well, I'd rather *replace* `a.model != b.model` with `a.model > b.model` ;-)

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Even if the OP is using implicit joins, your answer can do better. 2. If a.model > b.model, than a.model can't be equal to b.model - you have a redundant condition.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, super observation .. i will update

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is to change your query to use `<`:

```
SELECT a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram
FROM PC a JOIN
     PC b
     ON a.speed = b.speed AND a.ram = b.ram AND
        a.model < b.model
ORDER BY a.model DESC, b.model ASC;
```

Note that this also fixes your `FROM` clause to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're actually interested in the model numbers.
If not, you could try the following:

```
SELECT   speed,
         ram,
         COUNT(*)   AS number_models,
         MIN(model) AS min_model,
         MAX(model) AS max_model
FROM     pc
GROUP BY speed,
         ram
ORDER BY speed,
         ram;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on `Oracle`, `Postgres` or `MySQL` as *DBMS*, you can prefer using `least` and `greatest` functions together with *grouping* as below

```
select distinct least(model1,model2) as model1,
       greatest(model1,model2) as model2,
       speed, ram
  from pc
 group by greatest(model1,model2), least(model1,model2), speed, ram;

model1  model2  speed   ram
1121    1233    750     128
1232    1233    500     64
1232    1260    500     32
```

Comment: While this is a general solution for such problems, it isn't appropriate here. Eugene has shown his query and it's obvious how to avoid the duplicates. So why produce duplicates only to remove them with your aggregation afterwards?